# Placing spheres uniformly at random over $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, percolation

Put spheres uniformly at random all over $\mathbb{R}^3$, with density 1 sphere / unit cube. All spheres have the same radius $r$. What is the probability function $p(r)$, that that there is an infinite component, that is an infinite sequence of spheres such that the intersection of $s_n$ with $s_{n+1}$ is nonzero?

The distribution can be constructed like this:
Partition $\mathbb{R}^3$ into cubes of sidelength $L$ and put $L^3$ spheres uniformly at random inside each. Then we take the distribution that arises as $L$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists $r_c$ such that $p(r)=0$ when $r<r_c$ and $p(r)=1$ for $r>r_c$. The value $p(r_c) \in \{0,1\}$ is not known. Neither is $r_c$.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: The event {there is an infinite component} is translation invariant so by Kolmogorov {0,1} law, its probability is either 0 or 1.
the probability of this event is non-decreasing in r, thanks to a coupling argument, thus $r_c$ exists, It's a bit less trivial to show that $0<r_c<\infty$, but it can be done. I believe that $p(r_c)=0$, although i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: To be complete, you could add that for $r \geq r_c$, the volume is infinite.

Comment: Is it known for R^2?

Comment: No. only numerical estimates. What is known though in d=2 is the fact that the vacant (the complement of the occupied) has a transition phase at the same radius.